# MySQL Auto-Increment Issue with Numbering

Tags: mysql, database, primary-key

I have a table in my database with around 5m records, and I'm noticing the IDs of the each records are not incrementing by one any every insert.

For example, I have the following schema setup:

my_table
activity_id INT(11) PRIMARY (AUTO_INCREMENT), created_at DATETIME

If I look at the table and sort by the DATE TIME, the numbers are not sequential. It actually seems like MySQL is looking for when there is a deletion and then add the new record in there.

```
Edit    Delete  5000089     2012-03-17 04:31:46
Edit    Delete  5000087     2012-03-17 04:31:44
Edit    Delete  5000086     2012-03-17 04:31:43
Edit    Delete  5000085     2012-03-17 04:31:43
Edit    Delete  5000084     2012-03-17 04:31:31
**Edit  Delete  5000088     2012-03-17 04:31:30**
**Edit  Delete  5000076     2012-03-17 04:31:30**
Edit    Delete  5000082     2012-03-17 04:31:29
```

As you can see by the info about, at 4:31:30 GMT, we had 2 inserts, where it should have 83, and 84 but its incrementing weirdly. The database insert from the application does not specify the ID and the field of activity_id is set to Auto_increment.

Any help would be greatly appertained why this happening.

Has anyone see anything like this before?

Comment: Just curious but why does it matter if they aren't sequential with the date?

Comment: should we assume that the datetime value is generated by `NOW()` in mysql, or is it generated in a set of independent clent applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [auto-increment documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) has this paragraph:

> In this case (when the AUTO_INCREMENT column is part of a
>   multiple-column index), AUTO_INCREMENT values are reused if you delete
>   the row with the biggest AUTO_INCREMENT value in any group. This
>   happens even for MyISAM tables, for which AUTO_INCREMENT values
>   normally are not reused.

It seems to imply that index values are reused with InnoDB tables, and in certain cases in MyISAM tables. So, if you delete a row, there's a chance MySQL will create a new row with the old row's ID.